# docker toolboxのエラーについて

Tags: docker, windows-10

windows10にdocker toolboxをインストールしたのですが、
Docker Quickstart Terminalを起動した時にエラーがでてしまいます。

```
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
Looks like something went wrong in step Checking if machine default exists... Press any key to continue...
```

BIOS設定画面では、Virtualizationが有効になっているのですが、
上記エラーが発生しています。

また、VirtualChecker2というツールを使用して、CPUが「AMD-v」に対応しているか確認しましたが、対応しているようです。

数回、docker toolboxを再インストールしましたが、結果は同じです。

助けてください。。。
どうかよろしくお願いします。

```
OS: windows10 home
CPU AMD Ryzen 7 Pro 3700U
メーカー: lenovo(ThinkPad)

※情報足りなければご指摘ください
　windows10 homeにインストールしたいので、docker desktopは使えません
```

Comment: タスクマネージャーのパフォーマンスにある「CPU」の情報で「仮想化」の部分(右下にあります)は有効になっているでしょうか？また、Windows 10、VirtualBox、Docker Toolbox、BIOSファームウェアは全て最新(例えばWindows 10であれば1903)でしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。windows10のバージョンが最新でなかったため、Updateしてみます。そのほかも最新でない可能性がありますので、確認してみます。

Comment: 「仮想化」については、有効になっていました。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCスペック含めまったく同じ状況でしたが、古いバージョンのインストールで私の環境でも解決した模様です。

他サイトですが、
https://teratail.com/questions/199019

公式issueにも挙がっていて、
https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/830

以上から、以下のバージョンのインストで解決
https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/tag/v18.03.0-ce

Comment: ありがとうございます！こちら試させていただきます。（PCが修理中なので、近日中に,,,）

Comment: こちら、Dockerのv18.03.0をインストールしたところ、解決しました。ありがとうございます。